# How to create a custom view (using lookup) from aggregated data

Tags: postgresql, import, aggregate

**I have** data imported into a **postgresql** database:

```
groups (data import)
id | csv_user_ids
1  | 1,2,3
2  | 4,5,6
3  | 3,1,4
```

... and a lookup table for user names:

```
users (lookup)
id | name
1  | one
2  | two
3  | three
4  | four
5  | five
6  | six
```

I need to build a VIEW of `groups` with JSON column matching the user IDs as such

```
groups_view
id | json_array_users
1  | [{ 'id': 1, 'name': 'one'}, { 'id': 2, 'name': 'two'}, { 'id': 3, 'name': 'three'}]
2  | [{ 'id': 4, 'name': 'four'}, { 'id': 5, 'name': 'five'}, { 'id': 6, 'name': 'six'}]
3  | [{ 'id': 3, 'name': 'three'}, { 'id': 1, 'name': 'one'}, { 'id': 4, 'name': 'four'}]
```

How do I do that?

I guess I'd need to **disaggregate** rows in `groups` before aggregating into my new view again?

> JSON result is an array.

**source**:

```
groups (data import)
id | csv_user_ids
1  | 1,2,3
2  | 4,5,6
3  | 3,1,4
```

**to**:

```
group_user
group_id | user_id
1        | 1
1        | 2
1        | 3
2        | 4
2        | 5
2        | 6
3        | 3
3        | 1
3        | 6
```

How do I do that in SQL?

With `string_to_array(text, text [, text])` from [doc functions array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-array.html), I was able to turn the CSV string into an array *e.g.* `{1,2,3}`

```
groups (data import)
id | csv_user_ids 
1  | 1,2,3        => {1,2,3}
2  | 4,5,6        => {4,5,6}
3  | 3,1,4        => {3,1,4}
```

after what I tried `array_to_json(anyarray [, pretty_bool])` [doc functions-json](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html) ...

Comment: look this is the data I've got, not my choice. that's the source.

Comment: But are you able to insert the data into a properly normalized table?

Comment: Go and check the docs about array functions.

Answer (score 1):

### To disaggregate

```
SELECT id, 
   json_array_elements(array_to_json(string_to_array(csv_user_ids, ',')))
FROM groups
```

1. `string_to_array` converts the CSV string into ARRAY
2. `array_to_json`   converts ARRAY into JSON
3. `json_array_elements` each element into a separate row

next I just need to aggregate again.